# Is it possible to click on two buttons at the same time, if one covers the other one?

Tags: android, button, click

Sorry for the weird question, but is it possible to click on two buttons at the same time in android(having two logs, "clicked on b1" and "clicked on b2"), if one totally covers the other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not **ordinarily** possible; the top button will absorb the button click event and not pass it on to the one behind it. It is not clear whether or not you want to obtain this behaviour or avoid it, nonetheless, you can force it by propagating the event manually across the click listeners.

Here is one way (there are a few); assume buttonOne is on top of buttonTwo:

```
final Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(...);
final Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(...);

buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Log.d("ButtonTest", "ButtonOne clicked");
       buttonTwo.performClick();
    }
});

buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Log.d("ButtonTest", "ButtonTwo clicked");
    }
});
```

The click event enters the listener on button one, which then causes a click event on button two.

Here is another way which would work (and could be changed to support long click events easily):

```
final Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(...);
final Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(...);

final OnClickListener listenerTwo = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Log.d("ButtonTest", "ButtonTwo clicked");
    }
};

final OnClickListener listenerOne = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Log.d("ButtonTest", "ButtonOne clicked");
       listenerTwo.onClick(buttonTwo);
    }
};

buttonOne.setOnClickListener(listenerOne);
buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(listenerTwo);
```

Comment: I would like to obatin this behaviour. Could you show me a code how I can force it? As you said if I make a click event on both buttons the top one will absorb the click event.

Comment: What if I would like an onLingClickEvent on the buttontwo? So if my click is short, then buttonone's event completes, and if my click is long, then buttontwo's event completes? Is there perfromLongClick or somekind of that?  I still want two buttons, so making a setonclicklistener and a setonLongclicklistener is not good for me.

Comment: You can name the listeners, and then just refer to them directly at the right time (see answer). performClick() would do the same as listener.onClick(View); same applies to long click event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You will need to pass the click event that occurs on the foreground view to the background view. You can do this by checking where the click occurs and if it occurs within the view's bounds.

Comment: I am not sure how I could do it. Could you show me a code where you are able to check where the clck occurs?

Comment: You mentioned that the foreground button completely covers the background button implying that whenever the foreground button is clicked, the background button's click event should also be triggered, so do you even need to do any bounds checking? (And if that's the case, you may want to consider thinking your design over again)